# Ошибка addEventListener 'null'

Tags: javascript

Есть событие которое выполняется при изменении содержимых тегов iteminfo0 и iteminfo1

```
document.getElementById("iteminfo0 && iteminfo1").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
            inventory_logos();
            console.log(2);
        });
```

Выдает консоле ошибку

```
Execution of script 'SteamHelpMarkets' failed! Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Что я делаю не так? Мне кажется что DOM загружается после выполнения, но как исправить я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

`"iteminfo0 && iteminfo1"` - почему Вы решили, что `getElementById` распарсит это выражение и поймет, что там скрыты два `id`?

```
document.getElementById("iteminfo0").addEventListener(
  "DOMSubtreeModified", 
  function() {
    inventory_logos();
    console.log("iteminfo0");
  }
);
document.getElementById("iteminfo1").addEventListener(
  "DOMSubtreeModified", 
  function() {
    inventory_logos();
    console.log("iteminfo1");
  }
);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified

Comment: Я как можно составить условие чтобы отслеживалось изменения в одном из двух блоков? Дело в том что если изменения произошли из iteminfo0 в iteminfo1, то функция inventory_logos() вызывается дважды, как это можно исправить?

Comment: "изменения произошли из iteminfo0 в iteminfo1" - Вы думаете, я это понял?

Comment: в консоле два раза iteminfo1 или iteminfo0, то есть он два раза отслеживает изменения.

Comment: @MegaRoks Что здесь "исправлять"? Это правильное поведение.